# How to fix browser-issues in scss "automatically"?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

On developing frontend-stuff in scss and html5 I have some routines that I rely on like display:inline-block, rgba, css-gradients and so on.

Now dependent on which project I have, browser demands change. I sometimes need to deliver something workable for IE7 and sometimes IE10 is alright too.

Of course I can (and do) real browser checks to check issues, but I thought having a routine upfrontal check wouldn't hurt.  So I could run a search within my scss-files to check for the pattern "rgba" and replace it with something appropriate. But that doesn't sound neither very reliable nor modern to me.

Isn't there a way to generate a special set of pattern-fixes for each browser > run it > highlight it to me (or even better already fix it)

Would grunt/gulp be the topic I need to investigate therefore further?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Compass. Compass has a lot of built in support for older browsers and and you can set which browsers your current project should support. http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/

Comment: **DON'T** look at Compass to only fix browser issues. It's like raising an atomic bomb to kill an ant, it sounds powerful but you don't know what there's inside, and there are plenty non-desired side effects. Autoprefixer is the tools you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deolectrix said you could look into [compass](http://compass-style.org/), there is also [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/), and [less](http://lesscss.org/). Using grunt/gulp would be highly recommended. For many reasons like concating/minifying your code, or if you write JS you can use something like [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) to write ES6 JavaScript.

For cross-browser css [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) would probably help you out. For errors/warnings about troublesome css look into [csslint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint). Hope that helps! It's just a starting point, enjoy diving in.